# linking stylesheets and scripts in wordpress with functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I am following along with [this](https://www.taniarascia.com/wordpress-from-scratch-part-two/) tutorial.

I am trying to link the javascript and css files that are usually linked in the header using `wp_enqueue_scripts` in `functions.php`. With what I have now, only a blank white page is loading.

**functions.php**

```
<?php
// Add scripts and stylesheets
function blogtheme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '3.3.6' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'blog', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/blog.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.6', true );
    wp_register_style('OpenSans', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'OpenSans');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'blogtheme_scripts' );

// WordPress Titles
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

?>
```

**header.php**

I commented out the html links because I figured they weren't supposed to be in there once I linked to them in `functions.php`:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <!--<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <!--<link href="<?php bloginfo(//'template_directory');?>/blog.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <?php wp_head();?>
</head>
```

The page just loads as a white page, I'm assuming it's because something is wrong with the linking, and I don't see any errors in the console.

Could it be an issue with the versions of the scripts - `3.3.6`?

Answer (score 1):

If the tutorial says to put a call to `wp_head()` before the closing body tag, then the tutorial is wrong. It should be before the closing `head` tag.

Comment: I forgot to link to the tutorial - im going to update my question...but I have it before the closing `head` tag as well. I've tried it without it being before the closing `body` tag and no luck.

Answer (score 1):

[wp_head()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) is the function that loads your head template and should be located within the `<head></head>` tags in your template. The best place to put it is just before the `</head>` closing tag.

Comment: have you called your content with the functions that include your templates and The Content?

Comment: im not sure i understand, all I am trying to do is use the functions.php file to load the necessary scripts and stylesheets...im assuming `wp_head()` is what calls the wordpress functions to load the scripts.

Comment: It is, but you mentioned you had a blank page. does that mean you have no source code at all?

Comment: pretty damn blank `<html><head></head><body></body></html>` in inspector. I went back and tried adding the scripts using html just to make sure its the problem and it is...the theme works fine when i do it that way (the wrong way)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I usually get very fast help at the Wordpress forum, from the code wranglers. They know the code and the common pitfalls, because the forum is strictly for Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

The `wp_print_styles` should not be used anymore to enqueue styles (refer [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_print_styles)). You can add your google fonts enqueuing to your `blogtheme_scripts` function. I bet that will work :)

Comment: i did as you said...im still getting a blank white page

Comment: Are you using the google font on a plugin? If not, you can just directly enqueue it same to your other css files.

Comment: Are you using version 3.3.6 bootstrap and 3.3.6 jquery? It's weird that both have the same version. You can set that to `false` if you're not referring to that versions.

Comment: if there is a mistake with the versions..im not sure if `3.3.6` goes with jquery or bootstrap...i tried using false on each of them and still no luck

Comment: Try to enable `WP_DEBUG` on `wp-config.php` so could see what error the wordpress throws.

Comment: funny..i just got that response on the wordpress site at the same time..i did that..it was just a syntax error...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I enabled debugging in `wp-config.php` as suggested by an answer to this question on the wordpress site:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
```

After doing this I saw that I just had a syntax error - it worked after I fixed it.